# I installed Ubuntu on a separate hard drive but now my computer boots differently

Tags: boot, drive

I installed Ubuntu on a separate hard drive but now my computer boots differently and when I try to remove the hard drive my computer can't boot at all. Also my computer now automatically boots to Ubuntu.

I want Ubuntu as a separate boot drive (trying to learn more about Linux for school) but I don't want it to change my boot up and I want to be able to remove the hard drive from my computer and my computer to still boot.

Comment: Seems like you installed the boot loader on your *separate* hard drive. Provide more information as to which OS you want it to boot to automatically and if the *separate* drive is in fact a physically separated drive or a partition.

Comment: Did you install in UEFI mode or MBR mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options can be done

1.restoring windows bootloader.

2.restoring grub for linux.

1->put a windows cd or bootable usb and go into recovery option then find cmd and type the following:-

bootrec.exe

this will automatically repair your boot manager

2->put ubuntu cd or usb and reinstall it.